# yum install openssl-devel error

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, fedora, fedora20

On Fedora, `yum install openssl-devel` gives me the following error.

```
 Package: 1:openssl-1.0.1e-30.fc20.x86_64 (@anaconda)
           Requires: openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-30.fc20
           Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-30.fc20.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-30.fc20
           Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.fc20.x86_64 (updates)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.fc20
           Removing: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-39.fc20.x86_64 (installed)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-39.fc20
           Updated By: 1:openssl-libs-1.0.1e-42.fc20.x86_64 (updates)
               openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.1e-42.fc20
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by not updating your system before trying to install an updated package. There are conflicts between the update and other software already on your system. If you do a `yum update` before trying to install the individual package, you should be fine. Alternately, you probably could just update the specific affected packages: `yum update openssl openssl-libs`, and then do your install.

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar issue and I solved this by removing all conflicted libs with:

```
yum remove openssl-1.0.1e-30.fc20.x86_64
```

and so on and afterwards I installed them again and it solved my issue.

Comment: Is that meant to be `yum remove`?

Comment: @half i removed conflcted openssl